# Count number of times observation appears row wise pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like this:

| Area | Favorite Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| UT | Banana |
| TN | Grape |
| VT | Banana |
| AZ | Banana |
| CA | Cherry |

I want to insert a column with a count for how many times the fruit appears across the df like so:

| Area | Favorite Fruit | Fruit Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UT | Banana | 3 |
| TN | Grape | 1 |
| VT | Banana | 3 |
| AZ | Banana | 3 |
| CA | Cherry | 1 |

Trying to do this in python.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! [please paste data and code snippets in as block text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3888719), not pictures. images aren't searchable, can't be copied, and for me in this case, I can't see your examples because I'm viewing stack overflow in dark mode. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `transform('size')`:

```
df['Fruit Count'] = df.groupby('Favorite Fruit')['Favorite Fruit'].transform('size')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `value_counts` + `reindex`

```
df['Fruit Count'] = df['Favorite Fruit'].value_counts()\
                   .reindex(df['Favorite Fruit']).values
```